# AdjustTokenPrivileges: ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED after success

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, privileges

my code have a loop that use AdjustTokenPrivileges to enable SE_DEBUG_NAME privilege and remove it.
Every time the I run it, the first set of enable/disable is successful, but after the first loop, the rest sets of enable/remove's give ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED's for AdjustTokenPrivileges.
Machine is Windows 10 pro 64bit. The compiled exe run in "run as administrator" mode.
Please Help.

The following code is in a loop.

```
TOKEN_PRIVILEGES priv = { 0,0,0,0 };
HANDLE hToken = NULL;
LUID luid = { 0,0 };
BOOL Status = true;
if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken)) {
    Status = false;
    goto EXIT;
}
if (!LookupPrivilegeValueW(0, lpszPrivilege, &luid)) {
    Status = false;
    goto EXIT;
}
priv.PrivilegeCount = 1;
priv.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
priv.Privileges[0].Attributes = bEnablePrivilege ? SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED : SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED;
if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, false, &priv, 0, 0, 0)) {
    Status = false;
    goto EXIT;
}
std::cout << "priv:" << GetLastError() << std::endl; //gives 0(no error) on first pair of enable/disable, then 0x514, which is ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED, on the following loops.
EXIT:
if (hToken)
    CloseHandle(hToken);
return Status;
```

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375202(v=vs.85).aspx) tells you why:

> **SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED**:
>
> Because the privilege has been removed from the token, attempts to reenable the privilege result in the warning ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED as if the privilege had never existed.

Set the attribute to 0 to disable. MSDN has a example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446619(v=vs.85).aspx)...

Comment: Thank you. I understand how to disable it now. But if possible I still want to remove and re-add the privilege.

Comment: You are not allowed to add things to a token, once it's gone it's gone forever. Simply disable when you need to toggle on and off.

Comment: In general in a multithreaded process it's better to enable the privilege only for the current thread by duplicating an impersonation token. In this case it's ok to remove the privilege since you can simply revert to the process token. There could reasons to do this, probably related to how the Windows API in some cases automatically enables a privilege for the current thread. Removing the privilege ensures that can't happen.

Comment: @eryksun But you can't remove them in older versions. I usually write a wrapper that returns the initial state so only the last thread actually disables the privilege when every thread is done with it. I believe Windows also does it that way.

Comment: Removing privileges was introduced a long time ago, circa 2003. As to Windows, it used to use `BasepAcquirePrivilege` prior to Server 2003 SP1. The runtime library gained `RtlAcquirePrivilege` in Server 2003 SP2. By default this uses the current impersonation, or impersonates the process token (i.e. `RtlImpersonateSelfEx` since Vista). Optional flags support reverting to self first and using the process token directly (implies reverting to self). In the common case that uses a duplicated impersonation token, `RtlReleasePrivilege` only has to revert to self.

Comment: But, yes, if it uses the current impersonation token or is explicitly flagged to use the process token directly, then the previous token state is restored by `RtlReleasePrivilege`. I haven't made an exhaustive search to know if it ever forces using the process token. I don't see why it would. Anyway, without additional flags, it only ever needs to restore the token state when the thread is already impersonating.

Comment: I was referring to stuff at a much higher level, shell32 and up where they used to call `AdjustTokenPrivileges` like a normal person (IIRC)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Anders,

changing the line

```
priv.Privileges[0].Attributes = bEnablePrivilege ? SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED : SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED;
```

to

```
priv.Privileges[0].Attributes = bEnablePrivilege ? SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED : NULL;
```

fixed the code. But the code now only enable/disable the privilege.
As MSDN says

> The removal of the privilege is irreversible

So I cannot remove it and add it back on.

Comment: You can't, you have to pick one; disable or remove.

Comment: Assign the `DWORD` `Attributes` field a value of 0 to disable the privilege. `NULL` is semantically reserved for pointers (e.g. `(void *) 0`or `(char *) 0`), and possibly on some compilers assigning it to an integer may be an error.